# jQuery selector for elements in wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I use `$('.color-wrap div')` its select first div of both color-wrappers.

I need to select only first but they must be as a group so I can't use
`$('.colorbox:first-child')` or `$('.colorbox-hard:first-child')`.

I want to jQuery treat them as a group of 6 divs - its because, I want to choose one random div from group of six.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="color-wrap">
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="color-wrap">
            <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
            <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
            <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to select 1 div of div with class color-wrap only?

Comment: `id` must be unique within a document. You can't have same `id` multiple times.

Comment: i changed it for class'es but still same problem, jquery select both first divs from first and second color-wrap

Comment: First from each group?

Comment: You can use `$('.color-wrap div').first()`

Comment: I need to change background color for first div and then i will work on get random div from that 6 divs to change color, but $('.color-wrap div') change color for both divs, from first wrap and second wrap

Comment: your question is not clear, especially the first line: Did you intend to add `:first-child` to that selector?  From what you write afterwards, it seems so.

Comment: When i add :first-child it select both divs, from first wrapper and second wrapper, and I need only first Div

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divs = $('.color-wrap div');

for(var i = 0 ; i < divs.length; i++){
  console.log(divs[i]);
  // You can use like this.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="color-wrap">
    <div class="colorbox"></div>
    <div class="colorbox"></div>
    <div class="colorbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-wrap">
    <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
    <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
    <div class="colorbox-hard"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use also like this `var divs = $('.color-wrap .colorbox, .color-wrap .colorbox-hard');`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewBone I tried to explain before.. But it's too hard work for foreign. I can explain using my language. I just want to help and to inspire.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could do something like this. refer to comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Collect all divs for both wrappers in variable
  var group = $('.color-wrap').find('div');
  // Store the amount of items in the group variable
  var groupCount = group.length;
  // Store random number between 0 and the amount of items minus 1
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * groupCount);
  // Use the random number as the key for the group variable to store one of the divs
  var randomElement = group[randomIndex];
  console.log(randomElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color-wrap">
        <div id="colorbox">One</div>
        <div id="colorbox">Two</div>
        <div id="colorbox">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="color-wrap">
        <div id="colorbox-hard">Four</div>
        <div id="colorbox-hard">Five</div>
        <div id="colorbox-hard">Six</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply use a straightforward CSS selector, no need for all this JS.

Comment: @ProEvilz The question says they want to select one random div. How would you select 1 random div with a CSS selector?

Comment: This helps me to get random div from that 6 divs, so thanks for that, it solved my problem. Im intrested in ProEvilz solution also, can you tell how to do that?

Comment: I somehow missed the `I want to choose one random div from group of six.` So using a CSS selector won't pick one at random. If you wanted to target all or one of them, it would work. @WizardCoder is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.color-wrap:first-child div:first-child')` should do what you are looking for.